Custom Cursor Flickers Between Custom Image and Default Arrow in Web Application
I'm developing a web application (using HTML, CSS & Javascript) like the classic Duck Hunt Game, where I need to use a custom cursor (a crosshair) across the entire body of the document. Despite following best practices and ensuring compatibility, the cursor intermittently reverts to the default arrow, especially when moved rapidly. I've tried using both PNG and SVG images, resized to both 64x64 and 32x32 pixels, but the issue persists.
Here's the CSS I'm using:
body, html { cursor: url(<image path>); }
Steps I've tried:

Ensuring Cursor Size Limits: Confirmed that cursor images are within the 128x128 pixel limit supported by most browsers.
Optimizing Image Load: Used both PNG and SVG formats, ensuring images are optimized for web:
Preloaded the cursor image using <link rel="preload" href=<image path> as="image">.
Correct File Path: Double-checked the path to ensure it's correct.
Browser Compatibility Checks: Tested on multiple browsers (Google Chrome, Safari)

Despite these efforts, when I move the cursor rapidly across the screen, it sometimes flickers back to the default arrow cursor. This issue occurs inconsistently but is noticeable and affects the user experience.
Can someone please help with this issue?

body, html{
cursor: crosshair;
}
I tried this and it worked fine in my website

Without seeing the relevant code we can't help. It sounds as though you have some elements where the cursor is set to something else, but that's just a guess. Please put a runnable snippet into your question (remember to include the image). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
